# Regex capture words inside tags

Tags: regex

Given an XML document, I'd like to be able to pick out individual key/value pairsfrom a particular tag:

`<aaa>key0:val0 key1:val1 key2:va2</aaa>`

I'd like to get back

`key0:val0`
`key1:val1`
`key2:val2`

So far I have 
`(?<=<aaa>).*(?=<\/aaa>)`

Which will match everything inside, but as one result.

I also have
`[^\s][\w]*:[\w]*[^\s]` which will also match correctly in groups on this:

`key0:val0 key1:val1 key2:va2`

But not with the tags.  I believe this is an issue with searching for subgroups and I'm not sure how to get around it.

Thanks!

Comment: Match one level after the other instead of building one overcomplicated regex.

Comment: What language? This is what XML Parsers are for.

Comment: I have a two-level solution that works; the question I'm asking is can it be done in a single expression.  Let's say Python or PCRE.

Comment: How does your combined regex look like?

Comment: @AndreiVajnaII `(?<=<abc>)([\w]*:[\w]*)+(?=<\/abc>)` and variations are what I've been trying, also tried to work on using a kind of positive lookahead but couldn't get very far.

Comment: And this: `(?<=<abc>)([\w]*:[\w]*[\s]*)+(?=<\/abc>)` results in a very strange situation where there are two groups: all the first pairs, and the last one.  I've been using this: https://regex101.com/#python to test.

Comment: It's just much easier to make it done either with two regexes or without them at all :\

Comment: you can't do it with the re module of python since this kind of task needs the `\G` anchor. This can be done with pcre or the new python regex module: `(?:\G(?!\A)|<abc>)\s*\K([^<:]+):([^<:\s]+)` or if values can contain spaces:`(?:\G(?!\A)|<abc>)\s*\K([^<:]+):([^<:\s]+(?>\s+[^<:\s]+)*(?!\s*:))`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Ah now this is interesting, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot combine the two expressions in the way you want, because you have to match each occurrence of "key:value".

So in what you came up with - `(?<=<abc>)([\w]*:[\w]*[\s]*)+(?=<\/abc>)` - there are two matching groups. The bigger one matches everything inside the tags, while the other matches a single "key:value" occurrence. The regex engine cannot give each individual occurence because it does not work that way. So it just gives you the last one.

If you think in python, on the `matcher` object obtained after applying you regex, you will have access to `matcher.group(1)` and `matcher.group(2)`, because you have two matching `( )` groups in the regex.

But what you want is the `n` occurences of "key:value". So it's easier to just run the simpler `\w+:\w+` regex on the string inside the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded this one at [parsemarket](https://www.parsemarket.com/en/parsers/92), and I'm not sure its what you are looking for, but maybe something like this:

```
(<aaa>)((\w+:\w+\s)*(\w+:\w+)*)(<\/aaa>)
```

AFAIK, unless you know how many k:v pairs are in the tags, you can't capture all of them in one regex. So, if there are only three, you could do something like this:

```
<(?:aaa)>(\w+:\w+\s*)+(\w+:\w+\s*)+(\w+:\w+\s*)+<(?:\/aaa)>
```

But I would think you would want to do some sort of loop with whatever language you are using. Or, as some of the comments suggest, use the parser classes in the language. I've used [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) in Python for HTML.

Comment: Before understanding if it works you uploaded on parsemarket ?